# Deleted as Not An Answer?

Tags: discussion

Some apparatchiks (IMO) over on SO saw [this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/86043/80) and Rick's answer to it and were complaining to each other about that `it'd never be allowed on SO` (my paraphrase of the sentiment) and would be deleted as **Not An Answer** there.

Thankfully, one of the people in that discussion came here and actually did the right thing and flagged it, as well as linking to the discussion.

I get it. That's why I edited the answer and added a screen capture of one of the diagrams from the link.

But should it really be deleted as **Not An Answer** ?

Comment: More detail would be much better, but it's at least a partial answer. I think the overall content of SE benefits more from encouraging people to expand on their answers, rather than just deleting things.

Comment: That, and SO is a bit of a war zone compared to most other SE sites, so maybe they have to be a little more heavy-handed there.